# Accessibility Levels Issue

Tags: c#, overriding, internal, access-modifiers

This isn't the real question title, as I really don't know where's the problem, so I'm just guessing.

Story begins trying to send and receive a `dynamic` type to and from my WCF service which led me to [WCF Serialization of DLR dynamic types](http://loosexaml.wordpress.com/2011/01/01/wcf-serialization-of-dlr-dynamic-types/) !

**SerializableDynamicObject** Class

```
public class SerializableDynamicObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider
{
    private IDictionary<string,object> dynamicProperties = new Dictionary<string,object>();

    #region IDynamicMetaObjectProvider implementation
    public DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject (Expression expression)
    {
        return new SerializableDynamicMetaObject(expression, 
            BindingRestrictions.GetInstanceRestriction(expression, this), this);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Helper methods for dynamic meta object support
    internal object setValue(string name, object value) 
    {
        dynamicProperties.Add(name, value);
        return value;
    }

    internal object getValue(string name) 
    {
        object value;
        if(!dynamicProperties.TryGetValue(name, out value)) {
            value = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<string> getDynamicMemberNames() 
    {
        return dynamicProperties.Keys;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**SerializableDynamicMetaObject** Class

```
public class SerializableDynamicMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
{
    Type objType;

    public SerializableDynamicMetaObject(Expression expression, BindingRestrictions restrictions, object value) 
        : base(expression, restrictions, value) 
    {
        objType = value.GetType();
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember (GetMemberBinder binder)
    {
        var self = this.Expression;
        var dynObj = (SerializableDynamicObject)this.Value;
        var keyExpr = Expression.Constant(binder.Name);
        var getMethod = objType.GetMethod("getValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var target = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(self, objType),
                                     getMethod,
                                     keyExpr);
        return new DynamicMetaObject(target,
            BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(self, objType));
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindSetMember (SetMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject value)
    {
        var self = this.Expression;
        var keyExpr = Expression.Constant(binder.Name); 
        var valueExpr = Expression.Convert(value.Expression, typeof(object));
        var setMethod = objType.GetMethod("setValue", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var target = Expression.Call(Expression.Convert(self, objType),
        setMethod, 
        keyExpr, 
        valueExpr);
        return new DynamicMetaObject(target,
            BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(self, objType));
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames ()
    {
        var dynObj = (SerializableDynamicObject)this.Value;
        return dynObj.getDynamicMemberNames();
    }
}
```

Using this custom `SerializableDynamicObject` and after solving lots of issues, I finally stopped at a very strange behavior ( at least for me ).

@ **Service** *pseudo code* :

```
dynamic X = new SerializableDynamicObject();
X . Ask = "Stackoverflow";
Ping ( X ); // Send to Client
```

@ **Client** *pseudo code* :

```
// Receiving X SerializableDynamicObject
dynamic Y = X;
Log ( Y . Ask ); // Logging @ Chrome Javascript Console (Silverlight Client)
```

---

This consumed 2 days to reach it finally by luck :(

**Scenario I :**

Access Modifier for `dynamicProperties` member in `SerializableDynamicObject` class is **public**.

Client Log = `Stackoverflow`

**Scenario II :**

Access Modifier for `dynamicProperties` member in `SerializableDynamicObject` class is **private** or **protected** or whatever.

Client Log = `null`

---

**Question :**

- **Why** client output differs when changing the (`dynamicProperties` member) access modifier ?
- **Does** accessing members from internal methods (`setValue`, `getValue` methods) have limitation ( same class, same assembly, same namespace ) ?
- I assumed that problem comes from `SerializableDynamicObject` class **true** ? or It's from `SerializableDynamicMetaObject` class (`BindSetMember`, `BindGetMember` methods) due to **overriding** ?

I'm not that professional c# nerd, so please forgive me if it was too detailed long question to mention too trivial issue to be discussed !